# A different icon with a different name appears when I click the launcher

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I've noticed that some packages will create a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` but when I run the app a different icon with a different name would appear on the "favorites bar" (Ubuntu dock, or dash).

I've checked in different places but I don't seem to find a duplicated .desktop somewhere else.

.desktop in `usr/share/applications/`
[image: .desktop in usr/share/applications/]

Icon that appears when app got launched
[image: Icon that appears when app got launched]

Why is that, how can I solve it? (use the same icon for launcher and when launched). Also is there a way to know the path of the icon on the second picture directly from the favorites bar?

The .desktop file on `/usr/share/applications/` contains the following text:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/local/bin/matlab -desktop
Name=MATLAB
Comment=MATLAB
Icon=matlab.png
```